# Can i deploy my .war on an nginx server

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, server

I really love nginx for the stability and way 
requests are handled.

And i really love tomcat for the java 
and the user friendliness

Is there a way to deploy my .war on a nginx server ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible as nginx is not a servlet container, so it has no understanding of what a .war file is. You can configure nginx to act as a reverse proxy in front of a Tomcat server so this might get you the best of both worlds.

A quick Google search came up with this http://wiki.nginx.org/JavaServers which might give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Reverse proxy nginx to tomcat is like  tripling the request redirects user->nginx->tomcat instead you can configure tomcat and turn the tomcat on port 80 or 443 for best results   i used nginx only when there are multiple apps running on multiple ports like nodejs  + PHP combination

Answer (score 9):

Please try either of

1. Use Nginx as a reversed proxy in the front of Tomcat OR
2. Use [nginx-tomcat8](http://nginx-clojure.github.io/more.html#310-embeding-tomcat) to embedding Tomcat into Nginx to run war

Comment: my application is also war based, running on tomcat behind nginx but my css and js files are not getting loaded. can you please help?