# How to set up multiple exploded webapps (outside of $CATALINA_BASE/webapps) as ROOT in Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, nginx, tomcat, tomcat8

Here's a summary of what I need:

1. Run multiple apps in a Tomcat 8 instance.
2. These apps are exploded (not packaged as a WAR), and need to be in /misc/
3. They need to run as ROOT (ie no context path at the end of the URL)

I've managed to do the multiple apps as ROOT thing by using Tomcat's virtual host. In `/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/server.xml`, I have:

```
<Host name="qa01" appBase="qa01"
      unpackWARS="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>qa01.example.com</Alias>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="qa01_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

Then, I have the nginx conf as:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name qa01.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/qa01-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/qa01-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
}
```

So far so good, I tested it and it's definitely pointing to `/var/lib/tomcat8/qa01/ROOT/index.html`

The problem comes when I need this app to be in `/misc/qa01/webapps/ROOT/` instead.

I've tried adding `/var/lib/tomcat8/qa01/ROOT/META-INF/context.xml` with the following but it didn't work.

```
<Context docBase="/misc/qa01/webapps/ROOT/">
</Context>
```

Anyone has any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong (seems like a good night of sleep helps).

I need this in `/var/lib/tomcat8/exampleApp/ROOT/META-INF/context.xml`

```
<Context path=""
        antiResourceLocking="false" />
```

Then I need to configure the `Context` in `/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/exampleApp/ROOT.xml`. This is the thing that actually points to where my exploded WAR resides.

```
<Context docBase="/misc/qa01/webapps/ROOT/">
</Context>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

1. Use soft links in Tomcat `webapps` directory. Pointing to your deployed web applications. Assuming they are following Java EE Servlet standards. Please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452141/can-i-deploy-my-war-on-an-nginx-server).
2. Use `<tomcat-home>/conf/context.xml` configuration file wisely to manage the ROOT context. Please read more about this `context.xml` [here](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-context) and [here](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Context.xml).

Comment: Thanks for that! Option 1 seems to work, but it felt a little dirty, and I managed to figure out what I did wrong.